# Get most recent date from a date field which is common to most tables in SQL server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server database with 470 tables or so, most of these tables have a field with the same name which marks the last updated date, I need a query to get the most recent date value of all tables which contain that field, so query would be like,

Table name | last updated date

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *simple* way to do this.  One method is something like:

```
select max(lastUpdateDate)
from (select lastUpdateDate from t1 union all
      select lastUpdateDate from t2 union all
      . . .
      select lastUpdateDate from t470
     ) t;
```

You can construct this query.  One simple method is to do something like:

```
select replace('       select lastUpdateDate from @table union all',
               @table, @table_name)
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'lastUpdateDate';
```

(You might want to take schemas into account.)  Then copy the results and format them into a query.

Another helpful function is `sp_MSforeachtable`.  It is undocumented but there are plenty of articles on the subject, such as this [one](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx).  This can be a bit cumbersome if some tables are missing the column.

Comment: ok, I get it, but what do you mean by that last t; , is it a table name I should put there?

Comment: It is a table alias and required by SQL Server for subqueries in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been already said there is no wasy way; another one could be this but please keep in mind it uses dynamic sql with all of its pros and cons.

Moreover I'd suggest to set the column name you prefer instead of looking for it among all the dateime ones as I did, if it is always the same

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @strDate nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @maxDate DateTime
DECLARE @resDate DateTime
DECLARE @resTable nvarchar(max)
SELECT @resDate = '1900-01-01', @resTable = ''
DECLARE curTables CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name, c.Name
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.[type] = 'U' AND c.system_type_id = '61'
OPEN curTables
FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @tableName, @columnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@maxOUT DateTime OUTPUT';
    SET @sqlQuery = N'SELECT @maxOUT = MAX (' + @columnName + ') FROM ' + @tableName;
    exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery,@ParmDefinition, @maxOUT = @strDate OUTPUT;
    SET @maxDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @strDate, 102)
    IF (@maxDate > @resDate)
        SELECT @resDate = @maxDate, @resTable = @tableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @tableName, @columnName
END
CLOSE curTables
DEALLOCATE curTables
SELECT @tableName TableName, @resDate LastUpdateDate
```